# Arch Linux Libreoffice is problematic and slow in persian/arabic documents

Tags: arch-linux, libreoffice

There is no problem when working on English language documents, but if my document is Persian or Arabic, **libreoffice Writer** and **libreoffice Impress**  will slow down and other problems will occur.

Is this an error of Persian fonts Or **LibreOffice** is inherently problematic with Arabic Persian ?

this is my **libreoffice** information

```
Version: 7.1.8.1 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 10(Build:1)
CPU threads: 6; OS: Linux 5.15; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
7.1.8-3
Calc: threaded
```

Comment: a problem description could only be slighty more generic than "slow and other problems will occur". Did you ask in the LibreOffice forum / bug tracker and can you quantify / demonstrate the issue(s)?

Comment: No ~ but i found this bugs (NEVER SOLVED ): https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=64991 (for opening large RTL docs)
https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80788 <-- this was closed, maybe because it was too old and nobody verified it was still a bug?

Comment: Maybe give `libreoffice-fresh` a go; it's on version 7.2.4-3.

Comment: @ajgringo619 i could not solve problem by installing fresh version